# multiplication error of JavaScript and then

Tags: javascript

50000 * 1.1 is followed by a decimal point.
50000 + (50000 * 0.1) calculated correctly.

I found

1. There are limitations when expressing numbers with a computer.
2. When converting a decimal number to a binary phenomenon that an infinite decimal number is generated.
3. When expressing an infinite number as a finite number, there are values that are exceeded or lost, resulting in a calculation error.

And there are workarounds such as toFixed(), Math object method, and library.
I understand a bit, but I have a question.

Question 1.
If I use methods such as toFixed(), Math object methods, libraries, etc., do I get 100% reliability without any errors?
For example,  where calculations are important, such as in a bank, which method do you use?

Question 2.
50000 + (50000 * 0.1) gave no error.
However, unless a separate calculation error resolution method is used, When the number is changed, is there a there a calculation error?

Comment: Hope this video helps. Floating point arithmetic 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9F8pu5KfyM

Comment: Thanks. but This is what I have been looking for as well. I am curious about the error resolution method used in places that require reliability, such as a bank.

Comment: There is possibility of implementing yourself the logic of basic arithmetic for unlimited size numbers using strings or arrays. See for example [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) for the general idea

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some calculations would always have to be imprecise and rounded to some degree, regardless of the method you are using. In particular, calculations that involve irrational numbers such as Pi or the square root of 2. Those numbers cannot be expressed in a finite way so any actual calculation is inevitably rounded, though you can theoretically extend the degree of precision to whatever satisfies you.

In other cases, the calculation can be made accurate by using a different number system (with the help of a relevant library). For example, the fraction 1/10 can be expressed and stored precisely in base 10, but cannot be in base 2 which is the normal base computers use - which leads to errors with calculations that involve fractions like 0.1 . It's not that base 10 is necessarilly "better" - for example 1/7 would have to be rounded in base 10 as well, but using base 10 may be particularly useful when dealing with input based on ratios of 10, such as financial calculations.

There is also the possiblity of doing calculations with simple fractions, each consists of a pair of integers above and below the fraction line. It would be accurate as long as you are dealing with rational numbers, but might be significantly slower.